# Open New Tab in Lightning Out?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, navigation, lightning-out, workspaceapi

**Scenario:**

1. I want to create a `List Button` which displays a `Lightning Component`.

   - The only way to implement this step is to use a `Visualforce Page` which uses a `Standard Set Controller`, then use `Lightning Out` on that page.
2. I want this `Lightning Component` to include links which should open in a new tab.

   - The only way I can find to implement this step is to use `window.open`.
   - I tried out the [`<lightning:workspaceApi>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation), but it does nothing in `Lightning Out`. Nor does it fire any events I could listen for, as far as I can tell.

I read this post, which works well for a "supported" method of navigation in Lightning Out:
[How to navigate in lightning out?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/147556/2995)

However, it does not mention any way to open links in a new tab.

**Questions:**

Is there a supported way to open a record view (or any page) in a new tab when using Lightning Out? Is there any problem with using `window.open`, or any risks involved I should know about?

Comment: Workspace API opens a new tab in Lightning console Apps. Its not actually a browser tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any issues using `window.open()`. According to Locker API Viewer [`open`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) is supported.

I have a lightning component that leverages LDS sitting in lighting experience that opens a tableau external report using this method.

> **Reference:** [Leveraging Lightning Data Service in Lightning
>   Framework](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/leveraging-lightning-data-service-framework-rajesh-varma-mudunuri-/)

**NOTE:** This is my own blog post but the similar code is used for the tableau report!

**Based On Comments:**  Colors highlight the return types of APIs that are secured by the wrapper.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just gonna see if any other answers roll in. It's good to see that this particular function is supported, though. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianLarson Your welcome. Even I'm curious to see some good answer too!