# Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined] failed: $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-out

**Background**

I have a `Visualforce` page which loads a `Lightning Aura Component` using `LightningOut`.

When the Lightning component executes this line:

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

I get this error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined] Callback failed: apex://CustomProcessController/ACTION$clearSessionCache Failing descriptor: {c:CustomProcess}

I guess that `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()` is not supported in LightningOut?

**Questions**

What alternatives do I have to get the page to refresh?

And how can the Lightning component detect that it's running inside LightningOut such that I can use the alternative method?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: [How to navigate in lightning out?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/147556/2995)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Adrian Larson.

By adding this line:

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
```

To my `LightningOutContainerApp.app` it worked.

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:CustomProcess"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
</aura:application>
```