# Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined, $A.get('e.c.CloseConsoleTab').fire();

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have a Visualforce page which loads a Lightning Aura Component using LightningOut

In my Aura Component, I'm firing one Application event which will be handled by VF Page.
Now when I fire Application Event, I get the error, I'm firing my event like this:

```
 $A.get('e.c.CloseConsoleTab').fire();
```

I have also added the below dependency in my lightning out application, which is mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247445/error-in-a-getcallback-cannot-read-property-fire-of-undefined-failed-a). But still I'm getting the error.

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
```

Comment: How are you handling this in vf page ? Can you add your vf code as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `e.c:CloseConsoleTab`, not `e.c.CloseConsoleTab`. Also, check the event name, as they are cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. Also, if you mean `force:closeConsoleTab`, you're using the wrong namespace (this event does not appear to exist?), otherwise if you mean to use your own namespaced event, you're importing the wrong dependencies in your markup:

```
<aura:resource type="event" resource="markup://c:CloseConsoleTab" />
```