# how to open url in same window using window.open

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I want to open the URL in the same window I'm actually using the lightning component inside vf page so I can't use "Navigate To Url" as it only works in one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.
that's the reason I'm using Window.open is there is a way I can open the URL in the same window the way we can do this using "Navigate to URL".

```
handleOpenNewWindowWithRecordId : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('called');
   window.open("/006/o");
}
```

and if i use
window.open("/006/o","_self");
if just refresh the component and open the url there only
[image]

Comment: You would need to pass the listener function as an attribute from VF to aura component or VF page can listen an event send by aura component, an example here- [How to navigate in lightning out?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147556)

Comment: I guess no basically I need to create this url 
https://garvitasb2bsc--4hdev.cs60.my.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=5003C000003bdmt&parentname=0114054744&retURL=%2F5003C000003bdmtQAA
once my button is clicked
is there is any other work around

Comment: hmm, should have mentioned in the question originally that this page is embedded in standard layout. Maybe try: `window.open("/006/o","_parent");`, I would still handle the actual navigation in Visualforce page after listening to navigation event from the component..

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
handleOpenNewWindowWithRecordId : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('called');
   window.open("/006/o","_self");
}
```

Appending `_self` should force the page to open in the current tab/window.

Comment: It is actually refreshing the component itself I want to open in the same window attaching the screenshot in above question